# How to call this experiment research design?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, research-design

I am doing research in user interface design. I will conduct a user study where the participants will have to give label to a sentence(positive or negative sentiment). To label sentences, the user will have three conditions: 1. Labeling screen (control), 2. Labeling screen with Machine Learning Prediction and 3. Labeling screen with Machine Learning Prediction and Machine Learning Explanation.

Each of the participants will be assigned in one of the condition i.e one person only will be in one category and not the other.

I would like to measure whether the participants in one of the condition has higher user engagement and better perception of the tool compared to other study condition.
For doing so, I will collect a questionnaire with 5-scale likert to ask them whether the condition help them in labeling.

Thus I have Independent variable such as The condition (i.e., control, ML prediction, ML prediction+ ML explanation

Dependent variable - User engagement, User perception of the tool

Mediating variable
Experience To Machine Learning (novice / expert)

My question is : What do you called this research design? is it 3 X 1 between-subjects design? furthermore, how do I measure the result statistically,
is repeated anova is applicable here?